# Gridview textbox panel dropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, popup

One of the column of the Gridview contains a textbox.On setting the cursor focus on to this textbox  I would like a panel to drop down with  dropdownlist and a Add link. User when selects the options from dropdownlist and clicks add will insert the data to textbox of Gridview. Any idea how this can be accomplished ?. The gridview is inside the updatePanel.
Appreciate the help

Here is a Mock up of what I am trying to accomplish

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [TextExt](http://textextjs.com/) by Alex Gorbetchev? It allows you to do something very similar to this and is simple to use. I think it's actually what Stack Exchange uses to implement tags, but I'm not sure.

Example code...

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="1"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#textarea').textext({
        plugins : 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax arrow',
        tagsItems : [ 'Basic', 'JavaScript', 'PHP', 'Scala' ],
        prompt : 'Add one...',
        ajax : {
            url : '/manual/examples/data.json',
            dataType : 'json',
            cacheResults : true
        }
    });
</script>
```